# Should One Always Call EndInvoke a Delegate inside AsyncCallback?

Tags: .net, multithreading

I read the [Use AsyncCallback](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0420__Thread/UseAsyncCallback.htm), there is this code snippet:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging;
class MainClass
{
  delegate int MyDelegate(string s);

  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    MyDelegate X = new MyDelegate(DoSomething);
    AsyncCallback cb = new AsyncCallback(DoSomething2);
    IAsyncResult ar = X.BeginInvoke("Hello", cb, null);

    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue");
    Console.ReadLine();
  }
  static int DoSomething(string s)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("doooooooooooooooo");
    return 0;
  }

  static void DoSomething2(IAsyncResult ar)
  {
    MyDelegate X = (MyDelegate)((AsyncResult)ar).AsyncDelegate;
    X.EndInvoke(ar);
  }
}
```

Note that in `DoSomething2`, which is an `AsyncCallback`,  the delegate is explicitly killed by the command `EndInvoke`.

Is this really necessary? Because `AsyncCallback` won't get called unless and until the delegate method is finished running.

Comment: btw: Delegate.BeginInvoke is relatively inefficient when compared to using the ThreadPool, here's a page with some info: http://shevaspace.blogspot.com/2007/08/delegatebegininvoke-vs.html

Comment: @Yoooder, that suprises me because BeginInvoke uses the ThreadPool too. Read here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e08f6yc.aspx

Comment: It surprised me too, actually kind of shocked and disappointed me (it was my preferred pattern for async work) but nonetheless it seems to be a fact.  We've replicated the pattern in a custom implementation that uses the ThreadPool without the Remoting stuff in the way--all the benefits of the pattern, none of the overhead.

Comment: ...I also should have said "compared to using the ThreadPool directly".  The inefficiency is from the Remoting components/layers that are transparently at play; as @tuinstoel pointed out BeginInvoke() does in fact still use the ThreadPool

Comment: Casting the interface reference back to the implementation type - is a smell.. Doesn't seem to be a way around that - maybe a case of hindsight is always 20-20

Comment: @Gishu: It is of sorts, but as I mentioned above the Delegate.BeginInvoke() method should be replaced with an implementation that uses ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem behind the scenes to avoid the overhead of the remoting messaging....  so basically, the whole thing stinks (which, as I've said, sucks because it was my preferred pattern)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Calling EndInvoke() is very important.  If the background method generates an exception then calling EndInvoke() will raise that Exception, allowing your main thread to handle it.  Also, if the background method has a return value then the main thread needs to call EndInvoke() to retrieve that value.

If your background thread falls under either of these situations (generates an exception or has a return value) and you *don't* call EndInvoke() then the background thread won't be freed--essentially resulting in a resource leak.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes.**

There are a bunch of discussions all leading to the same conclusion - It's a resource leak if you don't.

search for MSDN's Caution [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e08f6yc%28VS.71%29.aspx)  and [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e08f6yc.aspx)
[IanG - EndInvoke not optional](http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2005/05/16/endinvokerequired)
[CBrumme's blog entry on async operations](http://blogs.msdn.com/cbrumme/archive/2003/05/06/51385.aspx)
A related question on SO - [Do I need to call EndInvoke after a timeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/557918)